# Override postion top of pseudo element on certain page

Tags: css

I am reusing a class that has a :before psuedo element, and want to overide a property when the element is within an element with a specific class:

I currently have:

```
.section-container.accordion .title::before {
    content: "\e025";
    font-family: "GeneralFoundicons";
    speak: none;
    display: inline;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 18px;
    top: 18px;
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: 0.3s ease;
    transition: 0.3s ease;
}
```

This is fine but on a particular page I want `top:0;` how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's as simple as defining the specific classname

```
 .your-specific-classname-page .section-container.accordion .title::before {
       top: 0;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, I'd added a space into my sass which was causing the issue.